# Gorilla websocket is not closing

Tags: go, websocket, httphandler, gorilla, net-http

I want to open websocket server whenever i want to and close but server does not close after writing "exit" when i go back to my main() and i try to start again it fails saying "httpHandleFunc multiple registration '/' " how do i close websocket server permanently and go back to main and start server again like switch on/off.

Another issue i am facing is client side errors with Bad Handshake when using gorilla mux as a handler.

#Server-Side Code

https://go.dev/play/p/n_I4xzOomWz

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

const (
    // Time allowed to write a message to the peer.
    writeWait = 10 * time.Second

    // Maximum message size allowed from peer.
    maxMessageSize = 8192

    // Time allowed to read the next pong message from the peer.
    pongWait = 60 * time.Second

    // Send pings to peer with this period. Must be less than pongWait.
    pingPeriod = (pongWait * 9) / 10

    // Time to wait before force close on connection.
    closeGracePeriod = 2 * time.Second
)

var (
    server   http.Server
    addr     = "0.0.0.0:443"
    upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
        CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
            return true
        },
    }
)

func ping(ws *websocket.Conn, done chan struct{}) {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(pingPeriod)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            if err := ws.WriteControl(websocket.PingMessage, []byte{}, time.Now().Add(writeWait)); err != nil {
                log.Println("ping:", err)
            }
        case <-done:
            return
        }
    }
}

// write message
func pumpStdout(ws *websocket.Conn, done chan struct{}) {
    defer func() {
    }()
    for {
        text := ReadInput("User220 > ")
        if text == "exit" {
            break
        }

        ws.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(writeWait))
        if err := ws.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte(text)); err != nil {
            ws.Close()
            log.Errorln(err)
            break
        }
    }
    close(done)

    ws.SetWriteDeadline(time.Now().Add(writeWait))
    ws.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, ""))
    time.Sleep(closeGracePeriod)
    ws.Close()
}

// receive message
func pumpStdin(ws *websocket.Conn, done chan struct{}) {
    defer ws.Close()
    ws.SetReadLimit(maxMessageSize)
    ws.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(pongWait))
    ws.SetPongHandler(func(string) error { ws.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(pongWait)); return nil })

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            break
        case <-ticker.C:
            _, message, err := ws.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                ws.CloseHandler()
                err := ws.UnderlyingConn().Close()
                fmt.Println(err)
                main()
            }
            if len(message) > 0 {
                fmt.Printf("\r\n%sUser220 > ", message)
            }
        }
    }
}

func WebsocketHandle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    stdoutDone := make(chan struct{})
    go pumpStdout(c, stdoutDone)
    go ping(c, stdoutDone)

    pumpStdin(c, stdoutDone)
}

func start_socket() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.Printf("listen at %s", addr)

    // ----------------------
    mux := mux.NewRouter()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", WebsocketHandle)
    //-----------------------

    http.HandleFunc("/", WebsocketHandle)
    server = http.Server{Addr: addr}
    log.Fatalln(server.ListenAndServe())
}

func stop_server() {
    err := server.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func ReadInput(promt string) string {
    fmt.Printf("\n%s", promt)
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    input, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    return strings.TrimSpace(input)
}

func main() {
    for {
        read := ReadInput("Main : ")
        switch read {
        case "start":
            start_socket()
        case "stop":
            stop_server()
        default:
            fmt.Println("Not Sure")
        }
    }
}
```

Client side i am just polling and writing back the same message right now.

#Client-Side Code

https://go.dev/play/p/y4nUkvMFYec

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

var addr = "localhost:443"

func main() {
    dial := websocket.Dialer{}

    u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: addr, Path: "/"}
    log.Printf("connecting to %s", u.String())

    c, _, err := dial.Dial(u.String(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()

    for {
        _, message, err := c.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("Recevied : " + string(message))

        err = c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, message)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have included the relevant code.

Comment: What is your goal in starting and stopping the http listener in the server application?  Why not leave the server running forever?

Comment: this websocket is just one part of the application, there will others features, user must be able to start server make communication and then close the server and use other features. the application is not ment to run on servers rather personal communication for personal computers.

Comment: I don't understand the goal of most of the code, but I'll give some hints on what I do understand. (1) Add `defer ws.Close()` to all functions that read or write to the websocket.  Return from any function  that encounters an error reading or writing to the websocket.  Remove all other code related to closing the websocket (2) Rely on the loop in `main` to restart the server.  Add `defer stop_server()` to the beginning of functions that read or write to the websocket server.  Do not call `main` from `pumpStdin`.  (3) Do not exit the program when `server.ListenAndServe()` returns.

Comment: Closing websockets seems a problem with Gorilla's implementation (https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/issues/448). 
https://github.com/nhooyr/websocket/ (an alternate websocket-implementation) allegedly solves it (together with some other flukes the Gorilla-WS-implementation seems to have).